# 4 images in one view using linear layout android

Tags: android-layout

I wish to make 2 by 2 image using `LinearLayout` with you equal weight. Can someone please assist me thanks. Your help will be appreciated thanks

I am trying to get my xml for my Android app working but I have some problems. I am trying to display to equal sized 2 images side by side in a linear layout. There has to be a margin between them, on both sides right and left, and on top.

[image: layout]

**MY code can only give me 3 images but I need 4 images.**
I'd appreciate any help solving this problem

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horiztontal"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note:further you can optimize this layout using Relative or ConstrainLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the Code split 4 images equally



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageview3"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageview14"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Each Image View Set the Scaletype property to set as FitXY